# Direct way to upload a file to specific folder in google drive through drive-rest-api using curl command

Tags: rest, curl, google-drive-api

I was writing a bash script that uploads the local files to google drive using curl command. In that, always I use to create and update(PATCH) the file using the google-drive-v3 rest query. 
Is there any way to upload the file to specific folders in drive directly?

Currently, I scripted that,

**1. Creating empty file in specific drectory.**

```
curl --request POST   'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files'   --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS-TOKEN]'   --header 'Accept: application/json'   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"name":"NEW_FILE_NAME","mimeType":"image/jpeg","parents":["DEST_DIRECTORY"]}'   --compressed
```

This will succesfully creating the empty new file in specified directory.

**2. Uploading file content as PATCH.**

```
curl --request PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/FILEID'   --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' -F "fileupload=@ubuntu-logo.png;type=image/png"   --compressed
```

This will update the file contents in the file id specified above.

Is there any way to merge the above two steps in single?

*Meanwhile, by this method of creating and updating the file is not generating the thumbnails to preview if it is an image/png file. Kindly resolve this issue also.*

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1:

- You want to upload an image file to the specific folder using curl command.
- You have already got the access token for uploading files to your Google Drive.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Sample curl command:

When you use this, please set the access token and the folder ID.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS-TOKEN]" \
  -F "metadata={ \
               name : 'NEW_FILE_NAME', \
               mimeType : 'image/png', \
               parents: ['DEST_DIRECTORY'] \
               };type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
  -F "file=@ubuntu-logo.png;type=image/png" \
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, the mimeType cannot be converted from `image/jpeg` to `image/png` at this API.

### Question 2:

- In your 2 curl commands (create and update), the thumbnail cannot be updated.

  - You want to know about this issue.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue:

In your curl command for updating the file, the metadata is not used. In this case, it seems that the thumbnail cannot be updated. If you want to update the thumbnail without updating all metadata, please add `-F "metadata={};type=application/json"` and please add `?uploadType=multipart` to the endpoint. By this, the thumbnail is updated.

The modified curl command is as follows. In this case, the curl command for updating the file was modified.

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl --request PATCH 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/FILEID?uploadType=multipart' --header 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]' -F "metadata={};type=application/json" -F "file=@ubuntu-logo;type=image/png"   --compressed
```

### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for your answer. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux or Mac use https://rclone.org/